# Raspbian /etc/network/interfaces file not present in ArchLinux

Tags: raspbian, networking

I am porting software system with central java application, "talking" to php webpage. In php webpage, there is a subsite for configuring network parameters, which in the code reads/writes from/to /etc/network/interfaces file. The older version of this system was based on Raspbian OS, but now we switched to Arch Linux, which has different network setup approach. I am thinking of creating /etc/network/interfaces file in Arch Linux and modyfing it through Arch Linux Network Manager. Does php maybe has some library, created for such purposes?

Comment: I promise there almost certainly won't be a php library for that specific purpose, but you may get some suggestions about the central problem here.

Comment: What files are involved in network configuration in Arch Linux depends on what tools you've chosen to use. Unless you're doing complicated things, `systemd-networkd` is a good place to start. It is configured in `/etc/systemd/network`. Read more about [network configuration in general](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration) and [systemd-networkd in particular](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd-networkd).

Comment: Ok, which tool should I use to get standard /etc/network/interfaces file?

Comment: `/etc/network/interfaces` isn't standard across Linux distributions. It's a Debian thing.

Comment: I've rewritten php subpage for network parameters. Now it is ok.